# Angular rxjs multiple subscriptions to ajax response observable firing multiple ajax requests

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

How can I make it so I can subscribe to the "child" observables piped from the "parent" without firing the main ajax request?

Please see full working MVP example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ndztje?file=src/app/app.component.ts) if necessary.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h3>{{ title$ | async }}</h3>
    <p>{{ value$ | async }}</p>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public response$: Observable<Response>;
  public title$: Observable<string>;
  public value$: Observable<string>;

  constructor(private fakeAjaxService: FakeAjaxService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // call the main ajax request to populate the response$ observable
    this.response$ = this.fakeAjaxService.request();
    // pluck the title from the response
    this.title$ = this.response$.pipe(pluck('title'));
    // pluck the value from the response
    this.value$ = this.response$.pipe(pluck('value'));
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `shareReplay()` to cache the result then `this.response$` will turn into a hot observable and only one request will trigger.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.response$ = this.fakeAjaxService.request().pipe(shareReplay());
    this.title$ = this.response$.pipe(pluck('title'));
    this.value$ = this.response$.pipe(pluck('value'));
  }
```